# Ubuntu Webcam does not work on Google Hangouts or Skype

Tags: skype, webcam, cheese

I installed my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside my Windows system. It's a ThinkPad E555 laptop. I just tried to use Skype and Google Hangouts today but could not get my built-in webcam to work. I would like to be able to use my webcam so please help if you can! Thank you very much!

I ran cheese and it shows "No device found":

```
** Message: cheese-application.vala:291: Error during camera setup: No device found
(cheese:4268): cheese-CRITICAL **: cheese_camera_device_get_device_node: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed
(cheese:4268): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
(cheese:4268): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
(cheese:4268): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
(cheese:4268): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given
** (cheese:4268): CRITICAL **: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed
```

I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get install cheese build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
[sudo] password for kangnahua: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
cheese is already the newest version.
linux-headers-3.19.0-58-generic is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer   required:
libntdb1 python-appindicator python-ntdb
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0     upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So cheese is the newest and the problem isn't cheese itself. Below is my lsmod:

```
lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
ctr                    16384  1 
ccm                    20480  1 
fglrx               13512704  162 
bnep                   20480  2 
rfcomm                 69632  8 
uvcvideo               90112  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         53248  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_core
videodev              159744  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
kvm                   479232  0 
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0 
crc32_pclmul           16384  0 
aesni_intel           172032  3 
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
arc4                   16384  2 
joydev                 20480  0 
serio_raw              16384  0 
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0 
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
edac_core              53248  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1 
snd_hda_codec_conexant    24576  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
edac_mce_amd           24576  0 
thinkpad_acpi          86016  1 
k10temp                16384  0 
fam15h_power           16384  0 
rtl8723be             143360  0 
btcoexist             413696  1 rtl8723be
snd_seq_midi           16384  0 
rtl_pci                40960  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi               135168  3 btcoexist,rtl_pci,rtl8723be
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
nvram                  16384  1 thinkpad_acpi
btusb                  40960  0 
mac80211              720896  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
snd_hda_intel          36864  9 snd_hda_codec_hdmi
bluetooth             491520  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
snd_hda_controller     32768  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         143360  5   snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_in    tel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
i2c_piix4              24576  0 
cfg80211              532480  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
snd_pcm               106496  6 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
shpchp                 40960  0 
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 fglrx
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    86016  26 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,thinkpad_acpi,snd_seq_device
soundcore              16384  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
wmi                    20480  0 
video                  20480  0 
mac_hid                16384  0 
parport_pc             32768  0 
ppdev                  20480  0 
lp                     20480  0 
parport                45056  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_generic            16384  0 
usbhid                 53248  0 
hid                   110592  2 hid_generic,usbhid
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0 
psmouse               118784  0 
r8169                  81920  0 
mii                    16384  1 r8169
ahci                   36864  2 
libahci                32768  1 ahci
rtsx_pci               49152  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
```

and my lsusb:

```
lsusb
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 5986:055a Acer, Inc 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Looks like an known problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1433906. My suggestion would be to get Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (released on the 21st of April), boot from it an see if your webcam is recognized, if yes upgrade you 14.04 to 16.04.

Comment: This [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hwe-next/+bug/1433906) is now fixed in Xenial / Yakkety -proposed kernel, if the verification task went well, it should be available in updates about two weeks later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an known problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1433906.
My suggestion would be to get Ubuntu 16.04 LTS burn it onto a DVD/USB-Stick (released on the 21st of April), boot from it and see if your webcam is recognized/working, if yes upgrade your installed Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.